# Adding numbers with decimal returns rounded number in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with three column:

Source / Target / Weight

x / y / 0.2

x / y / 0.2

z / a / 0.5

The "weight" column is as "float." I am running a select to group all of the duplicates and add the "weight" scores together. Here is the query:

```
SELECT source, target, sum(weight) as weight2
FROM mytable
GROUP BY source, target
```

Oddly, after I run the query, it seems that any value below 1 in the "weight" section (e.g. 0.2) is rounded to 1. So I obtain the following table:

Source / Target / Weight

x / y / 2

z / a / 1

Where the scores should have been 0.4 and 0.5. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you use `SUM()` or `COUNT()`?

Comment: Tried this on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b19f/1) and it seems to work as expected when using `float`. Can you replace the problem on SQL Fiddle with your create-script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran this on my instance of MySQL 5.5.30:

```
mysql> create table mytable (source char(1), target char(1), weight float);

mysql> insert into mytable values 
    -> ('x','y',0.2),
    -> ('x','y',0.2),
    -> ('z','a',0.5);

mysql> SELECT source, target, sum(weight) as weight2
    -> FROM mytable
    -> GROUP BY source, target;
+--------+--------+--------------------+
| source | target | weight2            |
+--------+--------+--------------------+
| x      | y      | 0.4000000059604645 |
| z      | a      |                0.5 |
+--------+--------+--------------------+
```

MySQL does not do rounding up to 1 as you describe.  All I can guess is that you rounded up the values as you inserted them.  I would recommend double-checking the data *without* doing a SUM() or GROUP BY, to see what the values are.

You may notice that in my output above, the SUM on the first row is not exactly 0.4, but instead it's a floating-point value *near* 0.4.  You should probably not use FLOAT if you are concerned about rounding errors.

Read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic, by David Goldberg](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDgQFjAB&url=https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf&ei=FpeOUfalMYK-0gHFlYDIBg&usg=AFQjCNEdaRdrUdVsgp-B6cqeLd9HS9Ezkg&sig2=vazC1V8LYZ6dVB0nSV1uMQ&bvm=bv.46340616,d.dmQ).
Or a shorter treatment of this issue in the MySQL manual: [Problems with Floating-Point Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-with-float.html).